# Trying to get a working web.config section for this programmatic AD FS configuration

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, web-config, adfs

I have the following programmatic code which I know works when I try to validate AD FS tokens:

```
var configuration = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration();
configuration.AudienceRestriction.AudienceMode = AudienceUriMode.Always;
configuration.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri("https://application.local/"));
configuration.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;
configuration.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online;
configuration.CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.ChainTrust;
var registry = new ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry();
registry.AddTrustedIssuer("<Certificate Thumbprint>", "ADFS Signing - adfs.example.local");
configuration.IssuerNameRegistry = registry;
SecurityTokenHandlers = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection(configuration);
```

However, I am trying to convert that to a working configuration so that I can just mark this all up in my `web.config`. I have tried this:

```
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
   <securityTokenHandlers>
    <securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
      <audienceUris>
        <add value="https://application.local/" />
      </audienceUris>
      <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust" revocationMode="Online" trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine"/>
      <issuerNameRegistry>
        <trustedIssuers>
          <add thumbprint="<Certificate Thumbprint>" name="ADFS Signing - adfs.example.local" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </securityTokenHandlerConfiguration>
   </securityTokenHandlers>
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

Using the following code (this time, not passing in my programmatic configuration):

```
SecurityTokenHandlers = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();
```

But the error I get when I try to validate tokens is:

> At least one 'audienceUri' must be specified in the
>   SamlSecurityTokenRequirement when the AudienceUriMode is set to
>   'Always' or 'BearerKeyOnly'. Either add the valid URI values to the
>   AudienceUris property of SamlSecurityTokenRequirement,  or turn off
>   checking by specifying an AudienceUriMode of 'Never' on the
>   SamlSecurityTokenRequirement.

So it must not be reading the configuration correctly. What am I missing? Is the code wrong? Is the config wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SecurityTokenHandlers = System.IdentityModel.Services.FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.IdentityConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers;
```

The config is correct.